# JS Calculations for numbers in text fields, and showing correct decimal points

Tags: javascript, calculation

I'm creating a form where people can list a product but the website takes a listing fee once the item sells

I've got a JS Fiddle working but my fields are not showing the correct decimal points

So:

1. you put a number value in the price field
2. then the JS puts the price including tax (12,5%) into the next field
3. then shows you the 25% that the website owner will receive once sold
4. the shows the amount the seller will receive once item sells.

You can see what I've managed to get working in the below fiddle, but my JS is just so sloppy and I'm not sure how to get it to work exactly how I want.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/Lq2cv4w9/1/

```
<form>
<table class="webform" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="CAT_Custom_2">Price</label><br />
            <input type="text" maxlength="4000" onchange="output()" name="CAT_Custom_2" id="CAT_Custom_2" class="cat_textbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="CAT_Custom_13">Price Including Tax's</label><br />
            <input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_13" id="CAT_Custom_13" class="cat_textbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="CAT_Custom_14">Cloudwine Commission 25%</label><br />
            <input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_14" id="CAT_Custom_14" class="cat_textbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="CAT_Custom_15">Seller Receives</label><br />
            <input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_15" id="CAT_Custom_15" class="cat_textbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="CAT_Custom_11">Listed Price</label><br />
            <input type="text" maxlength="4000" name="CAT_Custom_11" id="CAT_Custom_11" class="cat_textbox" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input class="cat_button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="catcustomcontentbutton" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CatalystScripts/ValidationFunctions.js?vs=b89.r513012-phase1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function output() {
   var value1 = document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_2').value;

  document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_13').value = parseInt(value1) * (0.125) + parseInt(value1);

   var value2 = document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_13').value;

   document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_14').value = parseInt(value2) * (0.25);

   var value3 = document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_14').value;

   document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_15').value = parseInt(value2) - parseInt(value3);

   document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_11').value = parseInt(value2);

 }

</script>
</form>
```

Comment: You are working with floats, so you should `parseFloat()` rather than `parseInt()`. Secondly, you can use `.toFixed(2)` to establish the decimal places.

Comment: Keep in mind one party or the other may not be happy with the rounding of the pennies :-)

Comment: All decimal points are correct, at least for a webpage in English. Do you want a commas instead of a points (as usual in most other languages: 7,50 instead of 7.50)? See http://brilliantmaps.com/decimals/ What exactly is your question?

Comment: if you put 100 in the first price field, then the tax should be 112.50 which is working, but the Coudwine Commission should be 28.13 after rounding